# Using select2 with pre-rendered HTML

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select2 in tagging mode to create and edit tags. There is an annoying behavior which is that there is a delay between when the page loads and when the tags appear. Since the tags can spill onto two lines, after the tags appear the whole page readjusts when the content below the tags box is pushed down.

The delay is caused by select2 converting the `input` HTML tag into the necessary HTML elements for each tag.

The delay could be avoided if the select2 didn't generate the HTML for the tags, but instead I generated it on the server-side and it was included in the original page load. Then the position of elements below the tags field would never change.

Is there a way to have select2 attach itself it existing - pre-rendered - HTML, rather than creating the HTML itself?

Does anyone know of a tag field components that supports this? All of the components I have seen start with an input tag and then generate the HTML dynamically using Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a satisfactory answer, so I created a JQuery plugin specifically for my use case: https://github.com/k1w1/rendered-multi-select

It has Rails helper to render the HTML for the control on the server, then the Javascript events are attached when the page loads. This results in faster and flicker free loading.